# Issue with imported data missing household address in NPSP 3.0

Tags: batch, npsp

I imported a bunch of contacts with household accounts (not using the npsp importer just the regular data migration tool).  Everything seemed to go in correctly but for some reason the address didnt copy up from the contact to the household.

I tried editing the contact to see if it would copy up, and no luck.  The strange part is when i edit the household on the visualforce page where you set the rules and select and address it shows there, but even if i save that the address is still blank.

The only way ive been able to get the address to update is if i click to change the address, select the same address again and then save?

There must be some way to batch this right?

Comment: This may be a record type issue or one of not having the proper relationship association with the household for the contact when you import it. Not certain as I don't do day to day admin stuff with NPSP. I only know those relationships need to exist for it to happen when you set these things up & would expect them to need to have the association with the household identified in the import data too. Its like when you import Accounts and linked contacts, except its a little bit more complex with NPSP's relationship objects that connect them.

Comment: Can you provide some additional details that might help?  Are you using the Household Account model?  When you refer to the Household, are you talking about a Household object or an Account object which is acting as a Household Account?  Did you receive any error emails during the import?  Also, while some of us are active here on SE, the best place to get answers to NPSP questions is at https://powerofus.force.com where there's a much bigger community of NPSP users and developers answering questions.

Comment: thanks for the info about powerofus.force.com will check there for those issues first from now on!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks guys for your comments, i was able to resolve the issues by mass updating the primary address type on the contacts which triggered the copy over.  I think it was just that i imported all the records with the data loader directly into contacts and accounts instead of using the npsp data loader object.

All fixed tho!

Comment: I have the same issue . I used the import wizard. Please can you tell me how to triggers a mass update on the primary address type which resolved this problem. Thanks